# Disable and enable p-step from primeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm currently using p-step to display a list of step a user need to complete a form. I want the user to only be able to do one step at a time and have all the other steps disabled. Then each steps will be enabled for them to click as they finish the previous step.

Currently the list of item in my p-step is generated dynamically from the back end. So each step route to another set of html/component files. So I'm not sure how to like sent information back and forth between this parent and the child in the step to disable and enable the steps properly.

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading else loading">
        <ng-container *ngIf="menuItem$ | async as menuData">
            <ng-container *ngIf="menuData != null && menuData.length > 0; else reviewNotStarted" >
                <p-steps [model]="menuData" [readonly]="false" data-cy="menu">
                </p-steps>
                <div class="container">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
```

I tried using input/output but given how this is dynamatically routed the example don't work and I'm not sure what to do.

So the end goal is basically each page it route to has a forum the user fill out then click a save/submit button. This will then enable the next step for them to complete. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi what you have to do is the following:

in the component.ts file

```
 menuData: MenuItem[] | undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reloadMenuData();
  }

  onActiveIndexChange(event: number) {
    this.activeIndex = event;
    this.reloadMenuData();
  }

  private reloadMenuData() {
    this.items = [
        {
            label: 'Step 1',
            command: (event: any) => this.messageService.add({severity:'info', summary:'First Step', detail: event.item.label}),
            disabled: !this.isStepOneValid()
        },
        {
            label: 'Step 2',
            command: (event: any) => this.messageService.add({severity:'info', summary:'Second Step', detail: event.item.label}),
            disabled: !this.isStepTwoValid()
        },
        {
            label: 'Step 3',
            command: (event: any) => this.messageService.add({severity:'info', summary:'Third Step', detail: event.item.label}),
            disabled: !this.isStepThreeValid()
        }
    ];
  }

  isStepOneValid(): boolean {
    return true; // Put your form validation here
  }

  isStepTwoValid(): boolean {
    return true; // Put your form validation here
  }

  isStepThreeValid(): boolean {
    return true; // Put your form validation here
  }
```

Comment: So my understanding is create a function that reload the status of the steps ever time something happens? What triggers onActiveIndexChange? Thanks!

Comment: yes correct, try this approach, similar approach I use in my project